# C++ Pop Function Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack

I am writing a program that implements stacks as linked lists. The program complies but when I run it, it crashes. I ran the debugger and says unhandled exception when it gets inside the Pop() function and to the line "topPtr = topPtr->next". I was wondering if anyone noticed something in there that is causing this error. I attached the portion of main and the pop function that I believe i sbeing affected. thanks

```
template<class ItemType>
struct NodeType
{ 
   ItemType info;
   NodeType* next;
};

template<class ItemType>
class Stack
{ 
private:
   int stacklength;
   NodeType<ItemType>* topPtr; // It points to a singly-linked list
public: 
    void Pop(ItemType &x);

template<class ItemType>
void Stack<ItemType>::Pop(ItemType &x)
{
    NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;
    tempPtr = topPtr;
    topPtr = topPtr->next;
    delete tempPtr;
    stacklength--;
}

int main()
{
Stack <int> IntStack;
int x;
IntStack.Pop(x);
}
```

Comment: That would happen if `topPtr` is `nullptr` or uninitialized. So 1: you need to make sure you initialize `topPtr = nullptr;` in the constructor and 2: you need to check stack depth on `Pop` (can't pop from an empty stack!).

Comment: `topPtr` is not initialized!

Comment: What do you expect `topPtr` to point to?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't initialize your pointers.

```
template<class ItemType>
struct NodeType
{ 
    //...
    NodeType() : next(nullptr) {} ///Initialize next so we can check for null
};

template<class ItemType>
class Stack
{ 
public:
    Stack() : topPtr(nullptr), stacklength(0) { } ///initialize
    //...
```

Then, in your `Pop`, you need to check for an empty stack (you can't pop if there are no elements).

```
template<class ItemType>
void Stack<ItemType>::Pop(ItemType &x)
{
    if (!topPtr)
    {
        //Here, we need to decide how to handle this.
        //One way would be to throw an exception,
        //another way would be to change the method signature
        //and return a bool.
    }
    ///...
}
```